# How to compare 2 images and get percentage size difference

Tags: c#, gdi+

how i can compare 2 images in c# suppose

- imageA size 1024x640
- imageB size 320x480

i want to know how i can get percentage of size imageb like
image B is nn% smaller than imageA

i did this but want to know if i am doing it right???
image A total pixels 655360 (1024x640)
image B total pixels 153600 (320x480)

so 
string ImageBSize= (153600/655360)*100 +" smaller then imageA";

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Calculate the areas of both and then divide one by the other. Seems like a simple math question, not a programming question.

Comment: string ImageBSize= (153600/655360)*100 +" smaller then imageA";
like this is it okay??

Comment: What's the real problem you are trying to solve? Comparing areas of images that have different aspect ratios is numerically easy, but what does it mean?

Comment: actually drawing watermark on images of different size 
user select images then select watermark image then adjust size of watermark image then he select other images and batch process all 
problem was i want to find the % of watermark size on first image
so i can pass that % of watermark size to other images of different sizes so it draw watermark perfectly @Bokkie answer helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using System.Drawing.Image or System.Drawing.Bitmap, you could just request the 'Size' property of each of the images. The 'Size' is divided in 'Height' and 'Width'. Calculate 'Height * Width' for each of the images and then you can calculate the ratio between the 'Sizes' of both images.

```
Image imageA = new System.Drawing.Image("ImageA.png");
Image imageB = new System.Drawing.Image("ImageB.png");

double imageASize = imageA.Size.Height * imageA.Size.Width;
double imageBSize = imageB.Size.Height * imageB.Size.Width;

string ratio = string.Format("Image B is {0}% of the size of image A", 
  ((imageBSize / imageASize)*100).ToString("#0"));
```

Comment: Be careful, I think you are going to get bit by integer division. If you made `imageASize` and `imageBSize` a double instead of a int I think it would work fine.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you're absolutely right. When using int's, the ratio will probably always be 0. I've changed the example.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is correct, but be careful that you cast (or assign) your values to doubles before you perform the division, otherwise you will get integer division which will always result in 0 if imageB is smaller than imageA.

You could do it in one line like this:

```
string ImageBSize = (((double) 153600 / 655360) * 100) + " percent smaller than imageA";
```

But it would be more readable and maintainable if you broke up your statement into smaller, clearer statements:

```
double imageASize = imageA.Size.Height * imageA.Size.Width;
double imageBSize = imageB.Size.Height * imageB.Size.Width;
double percentBIsSmaller = (imageBSize / imageASize) * 100;
string result = String.Format("B is {0:F2} percent smaller than A");
```

This would result in output like this:

```
B is 12.5 percent smaller than A
```